# spark scala selectExpr error in stack function

Tags: scala, spark

Использую следующий (Scala(2.11.12) + Spark(2.4)) код, который работает в spark-shell, но не работает из-под Oozie:

```
val columnsCount = newdf.columns.size.toString

val stackString = cols.map(x => {
val stackStr = s"'$x', $x"
stackStr
}).mkString(",")

val finalStackString = s"$columnsCount, $stackString"

val unpivotDF = newdf.selectExpr("evnum","evtime","syscode","job_app_id","request_id","stcode", "day", s"stack($finalStackString) as (field_name, value)")
```

получаю ошибку:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input ')' expecting {'('

(line 1, pos 9)

== SQL ==
stack(7, ) as (field_name, value)
---------^^^
```

По какой-то причине перестал заполняться 2й параметр при запуске кода в Oozie.